# How to run and hibernate from local computer ec2 instances to save costs

Tags: amazon-web-services, optimization, amazon-ec2

How can I remotely turn on the ec2 instance from my computer (ubuntu) and then turn it off (I want to use ec2 only while working on my pc and then hibernate to not pay unnecessarily.  Does hibernation mean no cost?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `awscli`.

You can easily do this and much, much more with it.

See here for download and more details:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-install.html

Once it's installed, you can do somethind like:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx
```

and

```
aws ec2 stop-instances --instance-ids i-xxxxxxxx
```

to start and stop instances.

If you stop an instance, you'll stop paying for the ec2 time.  But, you'll continue be charged for the EBS volume(s) that you have allocated until/unless you terminate the instance and make sure that all corresponding volumes are deleted.

Comment: Another method would be to provide an API Gateway endpoint that triggers an AWS Lambda function, which can then turn on the instance. Simply going to the URL would turn it on! I also recommend including a security key / password to ensure that only _you_ can turn it on.

Comment: That is true.  I guess it depends on the situation.  I'd argue that the solution you outlined is considerably more complicated, but I guess it really depends on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, but I noticed that it won't help me if I have to pay for Elastic IP anyway.
Can I deactivate ELASTIC IP address in the same way and when I run the instances, I'll make new one using CLI?

Comment: Elastic IPs are free if you use them.  If you have one allocated but not assigned to an instance, they'll charge you $0.01/hour (one cent per hour).

Comment: But, to answer your question, yes, you can create and destroy Elastic IPs with the aws cli interface.  You can do pretty much anything that can be done via web console, in the cli.